# JQuery, DRY. Click functions with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dry

This code isn't DRY.
This functions differ some variables and ajax requests, but they are very similar.

```
$(".increase-line-item").click(function(){
  var currentLineItem = $(this).parents("tr")[0];
  var lineItemQuantity = parseInt($(lineItemQuantityElement).text());
  // ...
  $.ajax({
    url: "/line_items/increase_quantity?line_item=" + $(currentLineItem).attr("data-line-item-id"),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(result){
      $(lineItemQuantityElement).text(lineItemQuantity+1);
      $(totalPriceElement).text(totalPrice);
      console.log(result);
  })
});

$(".decrease-line-item").click(function(){
  var currentLineItem = $(this).parents("tr")[0];
  var lineItemQuantity = parseInt($(lineItemQuantityElement).text());
  // ...
  $.ajax({
    url: "/line_items/decrease_quantity?line_item=" + $(currentLineItem).attr("data-line-item-id"),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(result){
      if (lineItemQuantity > 1) {
        $(lineItemQuantityElement).text(lineItemQuantity-1);
      }
      else{
        $(currentLineItem).fadeOut(200);
        $(lineItemsCountElement).text(lineItemsCount - 1);
      };
      $(totalPriceElement).text(totalPrice);
      console.log(result);
    }
  })
});
```

I want to do it the best way. How it do? Help me.

Comment: bind function like `$(".increase-line-item, .decrease-line-item").click(function(){` i.e.[Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: @timgeb Which makes it simply 'Too broad' on SO. No need for a custom close reason.

Comment: Please do *not* use 'belongs on siteX' as a close reason. The existence of another site does not make things off topic here. It may be too broad (at which point you can be helpful by pointing to another site), but please stick to our *usual* off-topic reasons.

Comment: See [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit since you changed your code**

Make a function for all your ajax stuff and bind it to the click event of both buttons. Check which button was clicked and depending on the button, determine the action:

```
function doAjaxStuff() {
  var currentLineItem = $(this).parents("tr")[0];
  var lineItemQuantity = parseInt($(lineItemQuantityElement).text(), 10);
  var action = $(this).hasClass('increase-line-item') ? 'increase_quantity' : 'decrease_quantity';

  // ...

  $.ajax({
    url: "/line_items/" + action + "?line_item=[...]"
  })
}

$(".increase-line-item, .decrease-line-item").on('click', doAjaxStuff);
```

Comment: ajax requests is differ for the functions

Comment: Yess!! It's work! Thank you, friend. You helped me a lot.